Navigation through "Narrow" Doorways etc
What are some suggested parameters for a robot's nav stack to pass though a simple doorway? My robot tends to get through - sometimes without issue. Other time (same door ways) not very elegantly - aka assuming it's stuck. Rotating in place et al (usual score).
I look at my bought vacuum robot that manages all of this with no difficulty at all. Can't help but think that ROS should be able to manage the same and indeed better.
LIDAR sensors etc. - hardware all the same (indeed I expect the vacuum, is much cheaper).
Appreciate any thoughts,
Thanks
Mark
